# Set of states with unequal probability where you can use less bits

Tags: probability, entropy

Say that we have a set of 16 colors.

- If they are equiprobable, the entropy is easy to calculate an kind of intuitive
- If they aren't it is just slightly less intuitive.

However, even if one of these states is very very likely compared to the others, is there any concrete way you could show how the number of bits would be reduced when representing them (not calculation-wise but notation-wise) ?

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what you mean by "notation-wise". For a binary encoding for a set of 16 colors, you'll need at least $\log_2(16) = 4$ bits to represent them, without compression. Knowing the entropy $H$ of the distribution of the colors you can optimally compress up to an expected length $L$ between $H$ and $H + 1$ (see for example [Huffman coding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding)). Does this help?